# Hide CMD Batch File/Windows after CHOICE selection is made

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

Im looking for a way to hide batch file / cmd window after a CHOICE has been made by the user.

Basically, when the batch is started the user gets three options which each of the option contains a TIMEOUT until the pc is locked.

So, when a selection is made the TIMEOUT should start and the window should be hidden automaticaly and continue run in the background.
When the TIMEOUT finishes the PC will be locked.

Would something like this be possible?

Currently used code

```
@ECHO off
cls
:start
ECHO.
ECHO TIME LOCK
ECHO.
ECHO 1.     65 Min
ECHO 2.     45 Min
ECHO 3.     30 Min
set /p choice=Select time to lock PC:
rem if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0;1% ( don`t use this command, because it takes only first digit in the case you type more digits. After that for example choice 23455666 is choice 2 and you get "bye"
if '%choice%'=='' ECHO "%choice%" is not valid please try again
if '%choice%'=='1' goto 60min
if '%choice%'=='2' goto 45min
if '%choice%'=='3' goto 30min
ECHO.
goto start
:60min
timeout 3600
rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
goto end
:45min
timeout 2700
rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
goto end
:30min
timeout 1800
rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
goto end
:end
::pause
exit
```

Short Specs:
● Windows 7, 64 bit
● 6Gb DDR3 Ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a batch script hide the console window, you can use `powershell -windowstyle hidden -command ""` to hide the window.  This is also a good way to minimize and restore the console window programmatically.  See [this Technet page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff629472.aspx) for more PowerShell command-line switches.

Of course, most people automating locking the workstation simply set the screensaver settings to require a password.  That way it locks after N minutes *idle*, and won't lock if you're in the middle of doing something.

Comment: thanks @rojo.
I works perfect.

Ps: I don't like using the screensaver for it activates after set of time when the PC is not being used. I need this small application to force me take breaks, so after every login start a timeout until auto logout.

Hope it makes sense.